# Getting the ValueError while taking the elements into the python list

Tags: python, arrays

I was doing this "Max element of the array" problem. While taking the elements from the user i'm getting an Value error saying "could not convert string to int".

```
n=int(input())
ar=[]
for i in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    ar.append(x)

print(max(ar))
```

Comment: That's because you're entering a value that cannot be converted to int. The clue is in the error message

Comment: what is the value in your input ? is it number for sure ? the code works just fine as long as the input is numbers

Comment: `could not convert string to int` is surprising, the usual exception when trying to convert a string to integer with `int` is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '...'`

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if input is number and make decision accordingly. don't be too successful oriented unless you expect to have those exceptions and knows to handle it.

for example :

```
j=input()
if not j.isnumeric():
    raise RuntimeError("input must be gte => 0 ")
n=int(j)
ar=[]
for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    if x.isnumeric():
        ar.append(int(x))

print(max(ar))
```

Comment: (1) the first variable should be n, not i (2) you are never converting the first input to an integer

Comment: `isnumeric` will return `False` if `j` is a negative number.